# How to backup a windows share to another windows share using rsync?

Tags: 11.10, server, rsync

I have two windows shares mounted and I would like to be able to backup the first into the second. The shares are found on a windows server 2003 machine. I was able to copy one folder to another windows share # 1, i figured I could use the same command.

```
rsync -azvv ~/mounts/share1 ~/mounts/share2.
```

I figure that's probably not the right way, but I haven't been lucky in finding something useful in google.

Answer (score 0):

That should work but you'd do better to walk* over to one of the Windows machines in question, mount the other and do the transfer directly.

<sup>*Or Remote desktop/telnet/whatever Windows uses for remote admin these days.</sup>

Using your method you're sending traffic through your computer and frankly Samba isn't *that* fast on Ubuntu. If you bring it back to a pure-Windows transfer between only two computers, you'll likely get better rates.

If this is something you need to do on a very regular basis, you might want to look at installing FTP server and client software that supports FXP. That (essentially) allows direct connections between two FTP servers to transfer files.